# Spark Scala - check field of nested case class

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have three case class as follow :

```
case class Result(
   result: Seq[Signal],
   hop:    Int)

case class Signal(
   rtt:  Double,
   from: String)

case class Traceroute(
  dst_name:  String,
  from:      String,
  prb_id:    BigInt,
  msm_id:    BigInt,
  timestamp: BigInt,
  result:    Seq[Result])
```

A **Traceroute** have field `result` which is a sequence of  **Result** . Each **Result** is a sequence of **Signal**.

I try to check if a field of `Result` is not negative.
My json record is as follow:

```
{"prb_id": 4247, "result": [{"result": [{"rtt": 1.955, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28}, {"rtt": 1.7, "ttl": 255, "from": "10.10.0.5", "size": 28}, {"rtt": 1.709, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28}], "hop": 1}]}
```

For clarity, I ommit some attributes in the json record. The **result** attribute is the result field in the Traceroute case class.

I used a filter to check if the rtt in signal is note negative by using filter, but I have not what expected.

```
val checkrtts = checkError.filter(x => x.result.foreach(p => p.result.foreach(f => checkSignal(f))))
```

The checkSignal function is as follow :

```
def checkSignal(signal: Signal): Signal = {
  if (signal.rtt > 0) {
    return signal
  } else {
    return null
  }

}
```

Given an example of two instances of Traceroute :

```
{"timestamp": 1514768409, "result": [{"result": [{"rtt": 1.955, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28}], "hop": 1}]}
{"timestamp": 1514768402, "result": [{"result": [{"rtt": -2.5, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28},{"rtt": 19.955, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28}], "hop": 2}]}
```

For the first Traceroute, no  changes to be applied.
For the second Traceroute, result.result field have two elements (type Signal), the first Signal have negative rtt, so I should delete this Signal from the result.result. But the second Signal should be not deleted.

As result, the ouput should be as follow:

```
{"timestamp": 1514768409, "result": [{"result": [{"rtt": 1.955, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28}], "hop": 1}]}
{"timestamp": 1514768402, "result": [{"result": [{"rtt": 19.955, "ttl": 255, "from": "89.105.200.57", "size": 28}], "hop": 2}]}
```

Any help please. I am new in spark and scala. I tried many ways but the result is not as expected.

Comment: Could you add what you are getting and what your expectation is? Add more data lines if needed to show the output properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a slight misunderstanding as to what filter function is supposed to do. It filters the whole `Traceroute` object from the dataset which return `false`. What you need to do is write a map function which will transform your original `Traceroute` object into the desired one. Below is a sample example as to how to do it for `Dataset[Traceroute]`

First you need to slightly modify your case classes as shown below.

```
case class Result(var result: Seq[Signal],
                   hop:    Int)

case class Signal(rtt:  Double,
                   from: String)

case class Traceroute( dst_name:  String,
                       from:      String,
                       prb_id:    BigInt,
                       msm_id:    BigInt,
                       timestamp: BigInt,
                       result:    Seq[Result])
```

As you can see I have added `var` to the `result` field of `Result` class. This will help us to modify the `result` field later on in your custom function which we would pass to the map operation

Then define the following two functions as below :

```
def checkSignal(signal: Signal): Boolean = {
    if (signal.rtt > 0) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }

  }

 def removeNegative(traceroute: Traceroute): Traceroute = {

    val outerList = traceroute.result
    for( temp <- outerList){

      val innerList = temp.result
      //here we are filtering the list to only contain nonnegative elements
      val newinnerList = innerList.filter(checkSignal(_))
      //here we are reassigning the newlist to result
      temp.result = newinnerList

    }

    traceroute
  }
```

Now we will map the original dataset from the transformed one where we recieve the filtered list properly.

```
val dataPath = "hdfs/path/to/traceroute.json"
val tracerouteSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Traceroute].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
val dataset = spark.read.schema(tracerouteSchema).json(dataPath).as[Traceroute]

println("Showing 10 rows of original Dataset")
dataset.show(10, truncate = false)

val maprtts = dataset.map(x => removeNegative(x))


println("Showing 10 rows of transformed dataset")
maprtts.show(10, truncate = false)
```

Following is the output :

```
Showing 10 rows of original dataset
+--------+----+------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|dst_name|from|prb_id|msm_id|timestamp |result                                                 |
+--------+----+------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|null    |null|null  |null  |1514768409|[[[[1.955, 89.105.200.57]], 1]]                        |
|null    |null|null  |null  |1514768402|[[[[-2.5, 89.105.200.57], [19.955, 89.105.200.57]], 2]]|
+--------+----+------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+

Showing 10 rows of transformed dataset
+--------+----+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
|dst_name|from|prb_id|msm_id|timestamp |result                          |
+--------+----+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
|null    |null|null  |null  |1514768409|[[[[1.955, 89.105.200.57]], 1]] |
|null    |null|null  |null  |1514768402|[[[[19.955, 89.105.200.57]], 2]]|
+--------+----+------+------+----------+--------------------------------+
```